# Fat Tire Bike versus Road Bike

Tags: fatbike

If I ride 20 miles on my Road Bike, what is that equivalent to on a Fat Tire Bike? More specifically (and technically), I would like to know how far I would end up riding on a Fat Tire Bike using the same amount of Watts as I would use riding 20 miles on my Road Bike. Many thanks!!!

Comment: Keep in mind that the rolling resistance of a road bike can vary probably by a factor of two based on tire choice and tire pressure.  But also keep in mind that, above maybe 8 mph, wind resistance is a bigger factor than rolling resistance, and wind resistance is dependent largely on your posture.

Comment: It makes more sense to ask how fast you'd ride on each bike, not how for you go, for a certain power.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad / unanswerable. There are some interesting answers with merit, but feel the question/answers is too chatty to be suited to the Q/A style of SE.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense."Watts" is a measure of power output, like horsepower for your car. Power determines how fast you go in a given situation. The only limit to how far you can go is how long you can keep cycling.

Comment: @mattnz - I apologize if my question was inappropriate. I will say that I feel I received fantastic answers that were thought provoking and helpful.

Comment: Nothing to apologize about. Many great questions just don't suit the Q/A model we use and are better asked on a chat or forum style site. See https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: @Sackaroo its a good question, but there is not a good clearcut answer.   If the question gets deleted as "too broad" its not a criticism of you or anything.  "best-performance" is such an ill-defined goal that people can and do argue about it indefinitely.  SE's QA model works best when there is a clear cut answer.  For more nebulous chitchat consider the [chat] part of SE, which scrolls away after a while.

Comment: Are you riding in the same conditions, or are you taking the fat tires through a foot of snow where your road bike would simply keel over and die?

Comment: The assumption is that all conditions remain exactly the same except day 1 I ride the road bike and day 2 I ride the fat tire bike. I’m just trying to get a sense for the difference in difficulty between the two different bicycles. I’m trying to simplify to the basics so I can determine in general how much further I can ride if I use the road bike and not the fat tire bike in the same time period — given that I expend the same amount of energy

Answer (score 4):

Super hard to measure without a power meter. But you could approximate it using various web resources.

https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com/ lists the best fatbike tyre as a "Schwalbe Jumbo Jim Liteskin PaceStar" with **36.9 W** of rolling resistance.  The best road tyre is a tubular at **7.7W** with most clinchers (ie normal tyres) under 20W per wheel and averaging 15W.

http://bikecalculator.com/ doesn't know about tyres specificially, but if you put 200W in and compare that with ~15W per wheel for a road bike and 36.9W per wheel for a fat bike, then you're effectively comparing 170W on a road bike with 130W on a fatbike.

Assumptions - 100 kilo rider (dressed)

170W on a 15 kilo road bike with hands on hoods, clinchers, over 10km will take 
**20.8 minutes** for a flat road or **122 minutes** up a 10% grade

130W on a 18 kilo MTB bike with hands on bartops, clinchers, over 10km will take 
**24.3 minutes** for a flat road or **164 minutes** up a 10% grade.  
I feel a fatbike would be even slower than a MTB.

This is excluding the aero differences between bikes too.

Comment: Thank you Criggie....I appreciate the quantitative answer! So, does this mean theoretically if I ride the Road Bike and the Fat Tire Bike both at 130 W, it should take me the same amount of time to travel 10km (all else being equal)? A bit confusing for me since I would think that spending 130W of energy on the Road Bike would take me further than spending 130W of energy on the Fat Tire - for the same amount of time.

Comment: 130 watts on the road bike will absolutely take you further for the same amount of time. Massive oversimplification ahead: On the fat bike, your tyres are each absorbing 36.9 watts, leaving 56 watts to forward momentum. On the road bike, you have each tyre absorbing 7.7 watts, leaving 114 watts to propel you forwards. Based on this alone, the road bike will be significantly faster, but even if you then decide to push harder on the fat bike to compensate for rolling resistance, you then have other factors such as the much higher aerodynamic drag and the heavier bike slowing you down as well.

Comment: @Carbonsideup yes I was working with 200W total rider output, and subtracting the power lost to each wheel, leaving 170W on the road bike and 130W on the fatbike.      I felt that was more "real world" than simply putting the same wattage on both styles of bike.

Comment: @Sackaroo in theory if you put road tyres on your fatbike (somehow) then the losses to rolling resistance would be about the same.  But a skinny road tyre is not going to fit the rims, which means replacing the rims and taking away the defining characteristic of a fatbike.   I suggest you play around at bikecalculator.com and see how things change wiht input.

Comment: @Sackaroo also, I ride 10,000 km a year and have no idea what my real power output is.  Best I've done is time myself up a hill with Strava, then find another rider of similar body-weight with a similar time for the same climb and use their number.   Maybe some test rides will be helpful for you, or look at buying two used bikes rather than one new bike.

Comment: @Criggie there's an article floating around the web somewhere that shows that assuming still weather conditions and a good road surface, the strava power estimate is actually pretty reliable on climbs

Comment: @Criggie "no idea what my real power output is"  Got any long hills (10 min or longer) that you climb slowly, say at under 10 mph/15 kph?  Average power in watts is given pretty accurately by `9.8 * ( total weight in kg ) * ( vertical distance climbed in meters ) / ( time in seconds )`.  You're not losing much to aerodynamic drag and rolling resistance at slow speeds, so the vast majority of your energy output goes into lifting you against gravity. (Watt units are `kg * m^2 / s^3`)

Comment: @AndrewHenle nice - the results look fair, but it is still an estimate not a measurement.  Only thing that will give a power measurement is a power meter, or similar instrument.

Comment: @Criggie I'd take an accurately measured climb power calculation over power meter output. A decent GPS track and a topo map will give you vertical distance within a few meters, and time within a second.  Get an accurate enough scale and you'll have your weight within a kg or two.  Under 10 mph/15 kph and not much wind you'll know your aerodynamic and rolling losses to within 5 watts given the total will likely be under 20 watts.  Ever take **your** powermeter and have it calibrated on a dynamometer?  At what temperature(s)?  How long ago?  Besides, all power meters have to estimate it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There are too many variables for us to give you any sort of accurate estimate based on the information that you've given us. Instead of trying to calculate as a distance based on that, you could do the experiment yourself. While a power meter would guve a more accurate equivalence, you can use a heart rate monitor to get a very good idea of your exertion on each bike.

Start by riding the 20 mile ride that you normally do on your road bike with the heart rate monitor on. At the end, you'll have an average heart rate for the ride and the time that it took. Now all you need to do is ride your fatbike for the same amount of time, while trying to maintain the same heart rate. You can repeat this as many times as you want at different heart rate zones to improve the accuracy as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost impossible to answer without more information.

If you are cruising at 15-20 kph on a flat road then there may be very little difference (depending on how much pressure you put in your fat tires).

If you were riding a fast 40-45 kph on the road-bike then you would be slowed down significantly by wind-resistance on the fat-bike and would travel a shorter distance on the fat-bike. Similarly if you were on hilly terrain where once again the road-bike would win out.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Penguino that this can't be answered as asked. With some more data, it would be possible to make some estimates. [Here is a power calculator you can use.](http://www.kreuzotter.de/english/espeed.htm)

Taking myself as an example, and assuming riding at 18 mph, I'd get this

Racing bike on narrow high-pressure slick tires: 181 watts
Mountain bike on fat knobby tires: 216 watts

If I ride for 1 hour at 181 watts of power output, that 181 watt-hours; if I divide that by 216 watts, I get about 50 minutes.

The difference will be amplified at higher speeds, and reduced at lower speeds, because aerodynamics are more and more important at higher speeds, and road bikes (more specifically, your position on road bikes) have a big aero advantage.

Comment: You both make good points. I am new to this and was thinking about getting a fat tire 4.8" bike. If I ride my road bike 15 miles (in Miami on the road) and it takes me 1 hour, I am trying to estimate how long it will take me using a 4.8" Fat Tire bike (assuming I spend the same amount of effort)

Comment: @Sackaroo: Your idealized approach seems like it would have too many variables to be a useful calculation. Suggestion: Borrow or rent a fat tire bike, ride it 15 miles, and see how it goes.

Comment: @GregHewgill thats a good answer by itself.

Comment: That power estimator is surprisingly good.